# Error on initialization of server mk-worker

Tags: java, maven, apache-storm, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to execute wordcount example using storm-0.8.1 and zookeeper-3.3.3 in local mode using maven. But, everytime i run this command i am getting following error:

`mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.test.newpackage.TopologyMain" Dexec.args="resource/words.txt`"

I searched and found earlier i was using zookeeper 3.4.5. So, then i changed my zookeeper to 3.3.3. but still not able to execute. If anyone wants to reference of my code here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17724937/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-topologymain)

```
 INFO  com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl  - Starting
    3706 [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2001] WARN  org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn  - EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x1401598b305000a, likely client has closed socket
    3857 [Thread-6] ERROR backtype.storm.daemon.worker  - Error on initialization of server mk-worker
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find component common for null
        at backtype.storm.utils.ThriftTopologyUtils.getComponentCommon(ThriftTopologyUtils.java:39)
        at backtype.storm.task.GeneralTopologyContext.getComponentCommon(GeneralTopologyContext.java:163)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod(Reflector.java:92)
        at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeInstanceMethod(Reflector.java:30)
        at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$normalized_component_conf.invoke(executor.clj:136)
        at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$executor_data.invoke(executor.clj:159)
        at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$mk_executor.invoke(executor.clj:233)
        at backtype.storm.daemon.worker$fn__4324$exec_fn__1207__auto____4325$iter__4330__4334$fn__4335.invoke(worker.clj:353)
        at clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval(LazySeq.java:42)
        at clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq(LazySeq.java:60)
        at clojure.lang.RT.seq(RT.java:466)
        at clojure.core$seq.invoke(core.clj:133)
        at clojure.core$dorun.invoke(core.clj:2723)
        at clojure.core$doall.invoke(core.clj:2739)
        at backtype.storm.daemon.worker$fn__4324$exec_fn__1207__auto____4325.invoke(worker.clj:353)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:185)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:151)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:600)
        at backtype.storm.daemon.worker$fn__4324$mk_worker__4380.doInvoke(worker.clj:322)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:512)
        at backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor$fn__4783.invoke(supervisor.clj:457)
        at clojure.lang.MultiFn.invoke(MultiFn.java:177)
        at backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor$sync_processes$iter__4660__4664$fn__4665.invoke(supervisor.clj:247)
        at clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval(LazySeq.java:42)
        at clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq(LazySeq.java:60)
        at clojure.lang.RT.seq(RT.java:466)
        at clojure.core$seq.invoke(core.clj:133)
        at clojure.core$dorun.invoke(core.clj:2723)
        at clojure.core$doall.invoke(core.clj:2739)
        at backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor$sync_processes.invoke(supervisor.clj:235)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:161)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:151)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:602)
        at clojure.core$partial$fn__3794.doInvoke(core.clj:2341)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:397)
        at backtype.storm.event$event_manager$fn__2484.invoke(event.clj:24)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
    3864 [Thread-6] INFO  backtype.storm.util  - Halting process: ("Error on initialization")
```

Answer (score 0):

According [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/storm-user/yFq63SUVk-M/ZNItjoTjKV4J) a similar problem was solved by re-ordering the dependencies. So I suggest you to move the zookeeper dependency element upper in your dependency list.

**EDIT:**

I suspect that your problem comes from a classpath order issue. i.e. the same class present in multiple artifacts and the version of the offending class currently loaded is *the wrong one*.

To workaround this problem you need to re-order your classpath (you probably know that when the same class is present multiple time in the classpath: the first one win). To reorder your classpath you need to change the order of the declarations in your pom.xml (at least since maven 2.0.9)

Quote from [maven site](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies) :

> since Maven 2.0.9 it's the order in the declaration that counts: the first declaration wins.

Comment: I didn't get your point. What do you mean by `move the zookeeper dependency element upper in your dependency list`? Even after reading the article i couldn't understand. Also, i am using `maven` not `leiningen`