# Errors while packaging using Apache Maven

Tags: java, maven, apache-storm

I am trying to run the [example](https://github.com/storm-book/examples-ch02-getting_started/zipball/master) code. However, I am facing some problems while executing the command as follows:

```
[root@sandbox our_application_folder]# mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="TopologyMain" -Dexec.args="src/main/resources/words.txt"
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Getting-Started 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.3.2:java (default-cli) @ Getting-Started ---
[WARNING] Warning: killAfter is now deprecated. Do you need it ? Please comment on MEXEC-6.
[WARNING]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TopologyMain
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:281)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9.783 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-09-30T03:00:25-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/75M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3.2:java (default-cli) on project Getting-Started: An exception occured while executing the Java class. TopologyMain -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Also, I notice another error as follows. I am learning to use Storm and Maven and hence not sure how to correct these errors. Do I need to download the missing packages?

```
[root@sandbox our_application_folder]# mvn package 
[INFO] Scanning for projects... 
[INFO] 
[INFO]------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[INFO] Building Getting-Started 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT 
[INFO]------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ Getting-Started --- 
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent! 
[INFO] Copying 1 resource 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ Getting-Started --- [WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent! 
[INFO] Compiling 4 source files to /root/teststorm/our_application_folder/target/classes 
[INFO]------------------------------------------------------------- 
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO]------------------------------------------------------------- 
[ERROR] /root/teststorm/our_application_folder/src/main/java/bolts/WordNormalizer.java:[5,35] error: package backtype.storm.topology.base does not exist 
[ERROR] /root/teststorm/our_application_folder/src/main/java/bolts/WordNormalizer.java:[10,36] error: cannot find symbol 
[ERROR]  class BaseBasicBolt /root/teststorm/our_application_folder/src/main/java/bolts/WordCounter.java:[9,35] error: package backtype.storm.topology.base does not exist [ERROR] /root/teststorm/our_application_folder/src/main/java/bolts/WordCounter.java:[12,33] error: cannot find symbol 
[ERROR]  class BaseBasicBolt /root/teststorm/our_application_folder/src/main/java/TopologyMain.java:[16,9] error: no suitable method found for setBolt(String,WordNormalizer) 
[ERROR]     method TopologyBuilder.setBolt(String,IBasicBolt,Integer) is not applicable
          (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
        method TopologyBuilder.setBolt(String,IBasicBolt) is not applicable
          (actual argument WordNormalizer cannot be converted to IBasicBolt by method invocation conversion)
        method TopologyBuilder.setBolt(String,IRichBolt,Integer) is not applicable
          (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
        method TopologyBuilder.setBolt(String,IRichBolt) is not applicable
          (actual argument WordNormalizer cannot be converted to IRichBolt by method invocation conversion) /root/teststorm/our_application_folder/src/main/java/TopologyMain.java:[18,9] error: no suitable method found for setBolt(String,WordCounter,int) 
[ERROR]     method TopologyBuilder.setBolt(String,IBasicBolt,Integer) is not applicable
          (actual argument WordCounter cannot be converted to IBasicBolt by method invocation conversion)
        method TopologyBuilder.setBolt(String,IBasicBolt) is not applicable
          (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
        method TopologyBuilder.setBolt(String,IRichBolt,Integer) is not applicable
          (actual argument WordCounter cannot be converted to IRichBolt by method invocation conversion)
        method TopologyBuilder.setBolt(String,IRichBolt) is not applicable
          (actual and formal argument lists differ in length) /root/teststorm/our_application_folder/src/main/java/bolts/WordCounter.java:[22,1] error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype [ERROR] /root/teststorm/our_application_folder/src/main/java/bolts/WordCounter.java:[33,1] error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype [ERROR] /root/teststorm/our_application_folder/src/main/java/bolts/WordCounter.java:[40,1] error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype [ERROR] /root/teststorm/our_application_folder/src/main/java/bolts/WordCounter.java:[44,1] error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype [INFO] 10 errors 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------- 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[INFO] Total time: 7.944 s 
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-09-30T02:38:27-07:00 
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/106M 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project Getting-Started: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /root/teststorm/our_application_folder/src/main/java/bolts/WordNormalizer.java:[5,35] error: package backtype.storm.topology.base does not exist 
[ERROR] /root/teststorm/our_application_folder/src/main/java/bolts/WordNormalizer.java:[10,36] error: cannot find symbol 
[ERROR] class BaseBasicBolt 
[ERROR] /root/teststorm/our_application_folder/src/main/java/bolts/WordCounter.java:[9,35] error: package backtype.storm.topology.base does not exist 
[ERROR] /root/teststorm/our_application_folder/src/main/java/bolts/WordCounter.java:[12,33] error: cannot find symbol 
[ERROR] class BaseBasicBolt 
[ERROR] /root/teststorm/our_application_folder/src/main/java/TopologyMain.java:[16,9] error: no suitable method found for setBolt(String,WordNormalizer) 
[ERROR] method TopologyBuilder.setBolt(String,IBasicBolt,Integer) is not applicable 
[ERROR] (actual and formal argument lists differ in length) [ERROR] method TopologyBuilder.setBolt(String,IBasicBolt) is not applicable 
[ERROR] (actual argument WordNormalizer cannot be converted to IBasicBolt by method invocation conversion) [ERROR] method TopologyBuilder.setBolt(String,IRichBolt,Integer) is not applicable 
[ERROR] (actual and formal argument lists differ in length) 
[ERROR] method TopologyBuilder.setBolt(String,IRichBolt) is not applicable 
[ERROR] (actual argument WordNormalizer cannot be converted to IRichBolt by method invocation conversion) 
[ERROR] /root/teststorm/our_application_folder/src/main/java/TopologyMain.java:[18,9] error: no suitable method found for setBolt(String,WordCounter,int) 
[ERROR] method TopologyBuilder.setBolt(String,IBasicBolt,Integer) is not applicable 
[ERROR] (actual argument WordCounter cannot be converted to IBasicBolt by method invocation conversion) 
[ERROR] method TopologyBuilder.setBolt(String,IBasicBolt) is not applicable 
[ERROR] (actual and formal argument lists differ in length) 
[ERROR] method TopologyBuilder.setBolt(String,IRichBolt,Integer) is not applicable 
[ERROR] (actual argument WordCounter cannot be converted to IRichBolt by method invocation conversion) 
[ERROR] method TopologyBuilder.setBolt(String,IRichBolt) is not applicable 
[ERROR] (actual and formal argument lists differ in length) 
[ERROR] /root/teststorm/our_application_folder/src/main/java/bolts/WordCounter.java:[22,1] error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype 
[ERROR] /root/teststorm/our_application_folder/src/main/java/bolts/WordCounter.java:[33,1] error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype 
[ERROR] /root/teststorm/our_application_folder/src/main/java/bolts/WordCounter.java:[40,1] error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype 
[ERROR] /root/teststorm/our_application_folder/src/main/java/bolts/WordCounter.java:[44,1] error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype 
[ERROR] -> [Help 1] [ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch. 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging. 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles: 
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: First fix your compilation errors otherwise the class you would like to use is not generated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TopologyMain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17724937/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-topologymain)